# Unable to open solution web site from visual studio 2005

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, solution

I work with Visual Studio 2005 and work on a web project which contains a web site. When opening the solution file, I receive the error message: "Unable to open the Web site 'http://localhost/myWebsite'. Visual Web Developer does not support opening SharePoint Web Sites. See Help for more details."  I can see the projects greyed out, with the remark "unavailable", in the solution folder so i can't see the code.

Has anyone had this problem in a similar way?
I'm not understand why i have this error..i try to install Visual Web Developer but the problem is still there

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1d71c090-de10-4b48-8ecf-20832d73347c/visual-web-developer-does-not-support-opening-sharepoint-web-sites?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Comment: @rene i try to install that..but not resolve the problem..

Comment: You installed  what? Both the extension and WSE 3.0?

Comment: That website at myWebsite really is an SharePoint site?

Comment: i think not..i think is web application

Comment: i installed this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=15052

Comment: @rene you have some ideas?

Comment: No, I have not. It is a bit long ago since I had to deal with VS2005 and WSS.